# Trying to get the minimum date and getting TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm reading from an excel file

`GA = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", sheet_name=0, engine= "openpyxl")`

The data type is:

- Email object
- Date datetime64[ns]
- Name object

I want to get only the row with the first date of an email

For example:

- A@gmail.com 1/1/2022 a
- A@gmail.com 2/1/2022 b
- B@gmail.com 3/1/2022 c

I'm trying to get only

- A@gmail.com 1/1/2022 a
- B@gmail.com 3/1/2022 c

I tried `GA.groupby('email')['date'].min()`

But I'm getting the TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'

i tried to change the date type to an object, tried to add reset_index(), tried to use agg('min) instead of min(), tried `GA.sort_values('date').groupby('email').tail(1)`
but keep getting this error, please help

Comment: Your `date` column contains integer.

Comment: No integar... All rows are in the same format of date

Comment: not sure if this is the issue, but Excel stores dates at integers i believe. ensure what you expect to be there is actually there. just saying "No integar" doesn't help because you're clearly getting an error that there is one.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your solution was only missing `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` for it to work, so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'email':  ['A@gmail.com', 'A@gmail.com', 'B@gmail.com'],
        'date': ['01/01/2022', '02/01/2022', '03/01/2022'],
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.groupby('email')['date'].min()
```

Output is:

```
email
A@gmail.com   2022-01-01
B@gmail.com   2022-03-01
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Tried that as well... Still getting the error

Comment: So as commented on the question, I believe you should take a look at your .xlsx file and check if any row on date column contains an integer by mistake

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, that the email had integer, not the date
thank you for your time